# Noise in Graphic Editor - Modify the "Restrict Frame Range" multi obj at the same time

Tags: modifiers

I have this[image]

Is there a way to modify the "Restrict Frame Range" value of all obj at the same time instead one by one?
I should set 500 from 750 the "End" setting.